# JavaScript_Truthy and Falsy Assignment_codecademy

Tags: javascript

Can somebody please explain to me why this code doesn't work?

```
let defaultName;
if (username) {
  defaultName = username;
} else {
  defaultName = 'Stranger';
}
```

It is used as an example at Codecademy, JS section.
An error stating username is not defined appears.

Thank you.

Comment: Because `username` is not defined.  Can you explain why you expect otherwise?  If the educational materials you're using cite this as an example, presumably there's additional context which this example serves to illustrate.  (It's also possible that the example is itself a mistake in the course materials.  That happens.)

Comment: @t3.0 nope, that doesn't make sense

Comment: @T3.0 That's not quite right. The error was that `username` is not defined. `defaultName` is undefined in the sense that its value is the `undefined` value (which is perfectly okay unless you try to access one of its properties or something like that), but `username` is not defined in the sense that the compiler has never heard of it (ie it hasn't even been declared, so the compiler knows that trying to run the program is a bad idea.)

Comment: It makes perfect sense unless the point of the Code Academy example is to generate an error. Otherwise one would assume username is defined outside the provided code block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to assign "username" to "defaultName", but you never declared "username". It may seem kinda funny, but in JS you assign values on the right to the variables on the left, so in your code:

```
let defaultName;
if (username) {
  defaultName = username;
...
```

this part is faulty, because you are telling the program to set "defaultName" to "username", which doesn't exist.

To simply get this code running, you would have to init the "username" variable like this:

```
let username = 'John';
let defaultName;
if (username) {
  defaultName = username;
} else {
  defaultName = 'Stranger';
}
```

Which is dull and pointless, because in a real app you would get the username from a form, from a database or from an authorization, this could be a real thing:

```
...
const user = this.props.auth.user;
let defaultName;
if (user) {
   defaultName = user.username;
} else {
   defaultName = 'Stranger';
}
...
```

This would be executed in *React* and, most probably, with *a ternary operator*, which you don't need to know just yet.

Comment: Thank you Nikolas. I am just a newbie, one day I will understand all what you have written!